# run the activity while it's not visible

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I'm working now in a project to download images from the web and then show it after completing  its download.

i made an activity class that has a button and text field and when the user press on the button, i started a service which will show a notification in status bar and after download i will show a message .

my main problem now is i want to go to other application or home page while the download is working.

i tried it but i after the download i got the message ,,, " Force quit"

should i use broadcast receiver or remote server to handle what i want.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The service should be the one downloading the content. If you go to the home activity our activity calls `onPause`, stoping all the work in progress.

Comment: but i don't need to stop all the work,, i need to complete while i'm doing another thing.

Comment: That is why you need to do it on a service. I didn't tell you that you needed to stop all the work. I told you what happens. You can't continue with your work when the activity is closed because she stops. As simple as that. The only (secure) way to do that is with a Service. [This link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)  (that Ricky also pointed out) shows you the Activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

Activities are just that, activities, they only work when visible and are built strictly for user interaction or a user activity, so this is impossible.  Use a service instead.  Here is a diagram showing lifespan of an activity:

[Link to App activity explanation on Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: i actually used a service, my problem is that when the download complete i showed a message saying you need to force quit.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call `Looper.Loop()` in your service to keep it running if you have any listeners in your service.